# IIS process w3wp.exe is not showing in Task manager processes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I am having a very weird issue that I am unable to see `w3wp.exe` anywhere in my system. I am learning ASP.NET using tutorials. In my computer `w3wp.exe` process is not showing in the taskmanager. Please help, I got frustrated by searching it throughout the whole day. I have `iis7.5` installed!

Comment: And you are 100% sure that you are running on local IIS and not on IISExpress or Cassini? By default VS is not using IIS to run local applications. Check the properties of your web project and make sure that "Local IIS" is selected.

Comment: Yes i was using IIS Express

Comment: If you like to stick with IIS Express the process you are looking for is called "iisexpress.exe"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try refreshing or showing all processes - I believe it's a checkbox option.

Then, refresh your browser and go for the attach to process option.

Comment: In Visual Studio it is a button.

Answer (score 37):

The `w3wp.exe` will not appear until the first request has entered the pipeline. So if you browse to your site and then open your task manager, you will see the `w3wp.exe`.

Comment: Click on "Show All Processes From All Users" in task manager.

Comment: BTW, which OS you are using?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: And Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate..Does this make any problem ?

Comment: In task manager Click on "Show All Processes From All Users". Open a webpage that is published on your system. Refresh task manager and you will see w3wp.exe process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55618/discussion-between-ricky-and-codesniper).

Comment: it shows after navigate to localhost:8000 through my browser (depend on port iis is running)

Comment: Correct Answer!

Comment: I was looking to solve not visibile on processes to "attach to process" list in VS, but it's the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

[image]Select `Show process from all users`

Comment: This really helped. I was trying whole day looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

In Task Manager processes it shows as IIS Worker Process, right click on it and click on 'Go to details' you will see w3wp.exe.

Answer (score 2):

you have to do following step to attached w3wp.exe

1. Open visual studio in administrative mode
2. Open IIS Application in web browser to you to attached debugger.
3. Debug>attached to process... Check the checkbox Show processes from all users
   [image]
4. refresh services and Search for w3wp.exe

Answer (score 0):

Bit long way but.. open cmd with "Run as admin" and type taskmgr and enter. This opens your Task manager with admin showing all processes including w3wp provided you make request to your application.